# Masking part of URL in jetty request log

Tags: security, logging, jetty, jetty-8

I would like to log all HTTP request in Jetty, which is well documented, but I can;t find any resources how can I mask some of the arguments.

E.g.:

`json/users/detail?id=dsgrw543`

should be logged as:

`json/users/detail?id=********`

or similar.

The main motivation is that I could give those logs for analytics, without worries that privacy of our users could be compromised. Ideally on-line, without using batch processing or other script.

Please note, that I use other authentication mechanism (cookies/all write methods are POST/etc.) and I can't change the existing URLs.

So far my only idea is to implement it as a class on top of NCSARequestLog:
http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/NCSARequestLog.html

What are the better ways of doing that?

Comment: Do you want to eliminate query string completely? Or just mask the values?

Comment: Just mask it value or eliminate that argument. I would like to keep query string. Even just throwing everything away after ? is fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

you may write a simple util like this, use it wherever you are logging

```
    Enumeration<String> s = request.getParameterNames();
    String q = "";
    while(s.hasMoreElements()){
        q += s.nextElement() + "=***&";
    }
    String url = request.getServletPath()+(q.length()>0?"?"+q:"");
```

or may be `request.getRequestedURI()` in place of `getServletPath`